# Joomla & JS; Sending data from form to Controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, joomla

I am having trouble with a form I created and trying to redirect the data someplace else by a JavaScript method that I call whenever the submit button is clicked.

The first thing that is happening, is that the form is created and filled in, then the user will click on the HTML generated button with this action in it:

```
onclick="javascript:saveEssayScore(<?php echo $key . "," . $pid; ?>);"
```

Secondly the script file is read and performed. The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("modal", "");

function saveEssayScore(key, pid){

    var user_id = document.getElementById("user-"+key).value;
    console.log("user " + user_id);
    var grade = document.getElementById("grade-"+key).value;
    console.log("grade " + grade);
    var teacher_answer = document.getElementById("feedback-"+key).value;
    console.log("teacher_answer " + teacher_answer);
    var question_id = document.getElementById("question-"+key).value;
    console.log("question_id " + question_id);
    var quiz_id = document.getElementById("quiz-"+key).value;
    console.log("quiz_id " + quiz_id);

    var req = new Request.HTML({
        method: 'post',
        url: "<?php echo JURI::base();?>index.php?option=com_guru&controller=guruAuthor&task=saveFeedback&tmpl=component&format=raw",
        data: { 'pid' : pid, 'user_id' : user_id, 'grade' : grade, 'teacher_answer' : teacher_answer, 'question_id' : question_id, 'quiz_id' : quiz_id},
        onSuccess: function(response, responseElements, responseHTML){
           alert('yeyy');
        }
    }).send();
}
```

Now in the URL, it is read to run the method (task) `saveFeedback()` in the controller `guruAuthor` which is in the component `com_guru`.

The problem I am having is, how do I read the data that I just send through the HTML request? I am trying stuff like `$user_id = JRequest::getVar("user_id");` But whenever I'm trying to echo or dump, it is returned to me but empty. Not the values that I am dumping in JavaScript `console.log(user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

[JRequest](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JRequest.html) is **deprecated**

Use JInput instead. Read - **[Retrieving request data using JInput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)**

In your mentioned code - if the controller function is being called, try this code-

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$user_id = $jinput->get('user_id', '', 'INT');
```

I hope this helps.